# How to add a second button code to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, button

How can I add a second button to this code in my `MainActivity`? I know I'm probably being stupid here, but not sure where I put the code for a second button to link to a different activity. My first button works fine, just not sure what to do for the second.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonabout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttonabout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

public void onClick(View v) {       
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Add it the same way as your first button by writing `Button button2 = ..` with the id from your second button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonabout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
buttonabout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AnotherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

    });

}
```

Comment: welcome @NicolaBA. i would appreciate if u tick my answer if it was useful. thnx :)

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
Button buttonabout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
buttonabout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... });

Button secondButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
secondButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to **add a Button in your activity_main.xml file,** the way you added first button. 
While adding this button, give it an ID so that to access it in your JAVA file.

For example:

```
android:id="@+id/mynewbutton"
```

Then get the reference of this newly added button in your MainActivity

```
Button btnNewButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.mynewbutton);
```

Now, set the click Listener on this button in same way as before.

```
btnNewButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //write your code for click on this button                  
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Another Way,It would be helpful to know what code you are trying to execute when the button is pressed. You've got the onClick property set in your **xml** file to a method called Button_Click.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="Button_Click"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

Now in your Java Class

```
public void Button_Click(View i)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AnotherActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);

}
```